# find intersections of 2 Piecewise Functions in ImplicitRegion

Tags: piecewise

How do I combine this two parts of a Piecewise functions?

I have trouble join this with `||`

```
g1 = ImplicitRegion[y == 2 - x, {{x, 1, 10}, y}];
g2 = ImplicitRegion[y == x, {{x, -10, 1}, y}];
g = g1 || g2;
h1 = ImplicitRegion[y == 2 - 2 x, {{x, 1/2, 10}, y}];
h2 = ImplicitRegion[y == 2 x, {{x, -10, 1/2}, y}];
h = h1 || h2;
Solve[{k \[Element] g, k \[Element] h}, k]
```

`Manipulate[g1 = ImplicitRegion[y == 2 - x, {{x, 1, 10}, y}];
 g2 = ImplicitRegion[y == x, {{x, -10, 1}, y}];
 g = RegionUnion[g1, g2];
 h1 = ImplicitRegion[y == 2 - m x, {{x, 1/m, 10}, y}];
 h2 = ImplicitRegion[y == m x, {{x, -10, 1/m}, y}];
 h = RegionUnion[h1, h2];
 sol = Solve[{k \[Element] g, k \[Element] h}, k, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 10],
 {{m, 2, "Times"}, -10, 10, 0.1}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g1 = ImplicitRegion[y == 2 - x, {{x, 1, 10}, y}];
g2 = ImplicitRegion[y == x, {{x, -10, 1}, y}];
g = RegionUnion[g1, g2];

h1 = ImplicitRegion[y == 2 - 2 x, {{x, 1/2, 10}, y}];
h2 = ImplicitRegion[y == 2 x, {{x, -10, 1/2}, y}];
h = RegionUnion[h1, h2];

Show[Region[g, BaseStyle -> Green], Region[h, BaseStyle -> Blue], 
 Region[RegionIntersection[g, h], BaseStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Medium]]]]
```

[image]

If you *have to* use `Solve`:

```
sol  = Solve[{k ∈ g, k ∈ h}, k]
```

> {{k -> {0, 0}}, {k -> {2/3, 2/3}}}

```
Show[Region[g, BaseStyle -> Green, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[k /. sol]}], 
 Region[h, BaseStyle -> Blue]]
```

> same picture

Comment: How to solve if I add manipulate? ``Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.``

Comment: how are gonna solve this problem?

Comment: @kile,  change the control to `{{m, 2, "Times"}, -10, 10, 1/10}` .